# Don't know why my nav is not aligned (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why (looking to achieve a drop down menu), my nav is not aligned horizontally, I've looked for every error I know, obviously didn't find anything. Can anyone help me to find the error? Or a way which I can use to make that nav aligned? :)

```css
body {
  background: #182530;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover>a,
.menu .current-item>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #be5b70;
}

menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #2e2728;
}

.submenu {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  background: #2e2728;
}

.menu li:hover .submenu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.submenu li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>
  Test Page
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
      <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li>
           <a href="current-item">Projects</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">WebIdentity</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LogoDesign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
       
      </div>
     </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I align my nav? Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need

```
.menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: SOLVED!! i forgot the "." before the class....sorry and thankyou for the answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code just by adding

```
nav ul li {
display:inline;
}
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ishan_Mahajan/e0w10b6m/1/)